# Proof of weak maximum principle for heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, maximum-principle

I am having trouble with the last step of the proof of the weak maximum principle for the heat equation, as found in

*Salsa, Sandro*, [**Partial differential equations in action. From modelling to theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-15093-2)

th. 2.4 pp. 36-38.

Here is a sketch of the proof.

Let $w_t - D\Delta w = q \leq 0$ on the *space-time cylinder* $Q_T$ with *parabolic boundary* $\partial_p Q_T$ 
and let $0 < \varepsilon < T$.

Defining the auxiliary function $u = w - \varepsilon t \leq w$, we have
$$u_t - D\Delta u = q-\varepsilon < 0$$ 
and we prove that 
$$ \max_{\overline{Q}_{T-\varepsilon}} u = \max_{\partial_p Q_{T-\varepsilon}} u$$
by a calculus argument: the Hessian is negative semidefinite and the time derivative is non-negative at the maximum, leading to a contradiction.

Moreover we prove that
$$ \max_{\overline{Q}_{T-\varepsilon}} w \leq \max_{\partial_p Q_T} w +\varepsilon T $$
essentially by subset properties w.r.t. maxima and the definition of $u$.

*So far, so good*.

Here comes the tricky part, at least for me. It goes

> Since $w$ is continuous in $\overline{Q}_{T-\varepsilon}$ we deduce that
>   $$ \max_{\overline{Q}_{T-\varepsilon}} w \to \max_{\overline{Q}_T} w \quad\text{as}\; \varepsilon\to 0 $$

therefore in the limit above we get 
$$ \max_{\overline{Q}_T} w \leq \max_{\partial_p Q_T} w $$
which concludes the proof since the opposite inequality is true for subsets.

My comments

- $w$ is not only continuous, but also uniformly continuous on the compact 
  $\overline{Q}_T$ and all its subsets, by Heine-Cantor theorem, but I cannot figure out how to use this property with the maxima.
- I have also explored the possibility that they meant 'uniformly *convergent*' instead of 'continuous', but this seems only applicable to other proof strategies, in which only $ \overline{Q}_T $ and not $ \overline{Q}_{T-\varepsilon} $ is used, like for instance in *Evans* (1998) ch. 7 th. 8. 
  For that line of reasoning, I am having trouble applying the triangle inequality to prove that 
  $$ \max_{\overline{Q}_T} u \to \max_{\overline{Q}_T} w \quad\text{as}\; \varepsilon\to 0  $$
  although this is slightly off topic.
- For $\varepsilon\to 0$ the sets $\overline{Q}_{T-\varepsilon}$ are increasing, therefore we can build a corresponding sequence of maxima which is increasing and so converges to its supremum over $\varepsilon$, but here again how can I prove that 
  $$ \sup_{\varepsilon>0} \max_{\overline{Q}_{T-\varepsilon}} w = \max_{\overline{Q}_T} w$$

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have a question about the end of the proof by Salsa, could you help?

Comment: @soundwave I am no expert, but if I can help I will. Feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for reply, before the "My comments" section you wrote "which concludes the proof since the opposite inequality is true for subsets.", but I don't understand what it means, could you elaborate more? Many thanks (in Salsa's book it is just written "which concludes the proof" without any further explanation)

Comment: Ok I got it! I was lost in a glass of water

Comment: Another question: why is the time derivative $u_t$ non-negative at the maximum?

Comment: Suppose $\max_{\overline {Q}_{T-\varepsilon}} u=u(x_0,t_0)\notin \partial_p Q_{T-\varepsilon}$. If $t_0<T-\varepsilon$ then $u_t(x_0,t_0)=0$ because it is a maximum on an internal point. If $t_0=T-\varepsilon$ then $u_t(x_0,t_0)\geq 0$ because the maximum is on the boundary and $u$ is non decreasing w.r.t. time. So $u_t(x_0,t_0)\geq 0$

Comment: grazie mille :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\Q#1{\bar Q_{#1}}\def\M#1{\max_{\Q{#1}}w}$Compactness and continuity makes this fairly easy. We know that the maximum over $\Q T$ is attained at some point $(x_0,t_0)$. If $t_0 < T$ then $\M {T - \epsilon} = \M{T}$ for all $\epsilon \in [0,T-t_0]$, so we are done; so we just need to consider the case $t_0 = T$.

Given an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, the continuity of $w$ provides a $\delta > 0$ such that $|w(x,t) - \M T| < \epsilon$ whenever $|(x,t) - (x_0,T)| < \delta$. Thus if we take a time $t > T - \delta$ we can conclude $$\M t \ge w(x_0,t) >\M T - \epsilon.$$ On the other hand we have $\M t \le \M T$ since $\Q t \subset \Q T$; so we have shown that $\M t \to \M T$ as $t \nearrow T$.

Comment: Thanks, the second part of your proof is clear; re the first part, I do not understand why for $t_0<T$ the maxima are equal. Is it because the corresponding sets are increasing w.r.t. time?

Comment: @GiovanniMariani: If the maximum over $[0,T]$ is obtained at $t_0 < T$, then of course the maximum over a smaller $[0,t]$ (with $t \ge t_0$) will again be obtained at the same point.

Comment: @AntonyCarapetis I see, it comes from the fact that $(x_0,t_0)\in \overline{Q}_{t_0}$ then $\max_{\overline{Q}_T} w=w(x_0,t_0)\leq \max_{\overline{Q}_{t_0}} w \leq \max_{\overline{Q}_T} w$