# What's a space-time cylinder?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What's a space-time cylinder?

As given here:

[Proof of weak maximum principle for heat equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392712/proof-of-weak-maximum-principle-for-heat-equation)

Comment: Some sources say that a space-time cylinder is in $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}$. But then there's e.g. this pic that suggest it's the space with $x,y$ and $t$ axes. https://www.cdc.gov/Mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/figures/su5401a13f1.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the domain

$$Q_T:=\Omega \times (0,T)$$

where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is the space domain, which shall be bounded. Now it depends on the source whether the time or the space comes first; and whether $0$ and/or $T$ are included in the time domain. For example see Evans "Partial Differential Equations" at the beginning of Chapter 7 where he looks at evolution equations.

EDIT: The notation of cylindric is quite loose, it means $Q_T$ has a kind-of-cylindric shape. $\Omega$ does not have to be a circle or something, it shall just be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example in "Partial Differential Equations in Action" by Salso on page 32 the following is an example of a space-time cylinder:

[image]

Comment: This is a simple answer.

Comment: Although, what's a "cylindric space domain"? You mean the volume of the cylinder? Or $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$?

Comment: @mavavilj Please see my edit. I hope it is clearer now.